# How to catch no permission error when changing directory in C++ Shell?

Tags: c++, linux, shell

For a school assignment, we have to make an own shell in C++. 
To begin, we are implementing the change directory functionality.
This is working like a charm with the chdir function.

But we got feedback that we have to catch the error that if the user tries to change to a directory without permission for it.

Does someone have any idea how to catch this?

Comment: Do you have a reference for your function like this one?  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html

Comment: Thanks for the reaction. It is quite useful, now I see what errors even are possible. Now it is the challenge to catch those errors.

Comment: Plenty of keywords on the manpage that you can search for :) On the one hand this would be an easy-rep question to answer (as it's actually a good question in terms of SO quality), but I'm hesitant because I think it would do you personally a disservice. I think it's best for everyone if we let _you_ answer this when you've figured it out :)

Comment: If you use POSIX `chdir`, it won't throw. It returns an error code. C++ does have `std::filesystem::current_path(new_path)`, and that will throw `filesystem_error`. So there might be a slight mix-up in terminology here.

Comment: Nobody said it would throw.

Comment: Hello guys. Small update, have not worked a lot on this project. But I have figured out that I can catch a return value by doing the following: int returnValue = chdir(cmd->args[1]). This will give me a 0 on success. If it failed somehow, it will give me a -1 right? But how do I catch EACCES, EFAULT, EIO and such?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

```
if (chdir(cmd->args[1]) != 0){
    perror("Changing directory failed");
}
```

This prints the exact reason why change directory failed.

Thanks for all the help / reactions.